# SparkSQL equivalent for SQL compiled statement with variables

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to execute SparkSQL statements in an efficient manner. Eg. compile once, execute many times (with different parameter values).

For a simple SQL example:

```
select * from my_table where year=:1
```

where :1 is a bind variable, and thus the statement is only compiled once, and executed N times (with different values), I need the same SparkSQL equivalente.

Things like:

```
year = 2020
df_result = spark.sql("select * from my_table where year={0}".format(year))
```

are not what I expect, since are not really bound variables, but just one specific instantiated sentence.

Comment: Why do you need this? For performance? I think you will find that your example with string interpolation will serve you well and fast.

Comment: Indeed, it is in terms of performance. If you happen to execute this statement thousands of times, it is fair to take a look at alternative for avoiding to recompute the statement each time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your data are stored, your cluster resources, size of table etc... you **might** consider caching the entire table, that will at least prevent spark from having to read off disk/blob storage on every execution of the query

```
catalog = sparkSession.catalog

if catalog.isCached("my_table")):
  df_my_table.cache()

df_result = df_my_table.filter("year='" + str(year) + "'")
```

There may be many ways to do this better depending on your architecture, but i'm sticking to a 100% spark based solution here